# How to create custom links in the Application.FileDialog using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, dialog, hyperlink, openfiledialog

I am attempting to use the FileDialog construct in VBA to display a list of available files the user may want to open. I would like to also steer the user towards some common folders in which they typically will find the type of content they are looking for. So far I have come short on locating a method to place a link on the left side of the FileDialog box in which they could click to jump to a specific location.

I am hoping there is a means of doing this while calling the FileDialog methods like an example shown below where I have used the `fd.AddLinkMethod "<path goes here>"`.

```
Private Function GetLocation() As String
     Dim fd As FileDialog
     Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
     Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

     fd.ButtonName = "Open"
     fd.Title = "Select File To Open"
     fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewTiles

     fd.AddLinkMethod "<path goes here>"

     With fd
         If .Show = -1 Then

             For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                 GetLocation= FormatPath(vrtSelectedItem)
             Next vrtSelectedItem

           End If
      End With     

      Set fd = Nothing
 End Function
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am attempting to accomplish?

[image]

Any pointers?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be do-able, but you will need to switch from the access filedialog, and use the Windows Common Dialog from the windows API. ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161286 ) Then there are a few ways to modify the links that are pointed out in this article ( http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-more-ways-to-customize-common-dialog-open-in-windows-xp/ ). Not the most elegant, but it should work.  Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for fixing my links David